# Solr search(sort) by having count

Tags: solr

Is it possible to search in Solr like in mysql by having count?

```
SELECT 
    u.* 
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN post p ON p.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id
HAVING COUNT(p.id) < 10
```

I have schema with next fields: id, type, data
If I add new field "posts_count" I can write next query:

```
q=type:user AND posts_count:[0 TO 9]
```

But I can't add new field(for internal reasons)

And next similar question. Is it possible to sort by calculated count

```
ORDER BY count(p.id) DESC
q=type:user&sort=posts_count DESC
```

**Solr version 6.6**

*p.s. I'm pretty new in Solr*

Comment: What about to use facet count?

Comment: @Oyeme Yes, I can use facet, but in this case I need two queries, first query to get ids with users from facet, and second query to get users by ids, and I want use one query. Is it possible?